# How To create Array Of 100 With Integers From 1-1000?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I know how to create an array of 100 with integers from 1-100 which will be just:

```
int [] array = new int[100];                       // Sorted Array of 100
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    array[a] = a + 1;
}
```

But my question is how to create an array of 100 with some sorted integers from 1-1000, inclusive. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
int [] array = new int[100];
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    array[a] = (a + 1) * 10;
}
```

Simple, if you have no other requirement.

Edit: To make it almost sorted (like every 10th unsorted element), there are many ways. One, using BevynQ's solution, can be:

```
Random r = new Random();
int [] array = new int[100];
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if ((a + 1) % 10 != 0) {
        array[a] = (a + 1) * 10;
    } else {
        array[a] = r.nextInt(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I actually do have another question if i want to make that "almost sorted" how would i do that i did shuffle but that's not almost sorted?

Comment: What do you mean by almost sorted? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Anything works as long as its not sorted and not completely unsorted. I tried swapping every 10th node but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using random

```
Random r = new Random();
int [] array = new int[100];
int last = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    last = last + r.nextInt(10) + 1;
    array[a] = last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Now I was trying to make it "almost sorted" how would i do that i did shuffle but that's not almost sorted

Comment: That depends on what you mean by almost sorted

Comment: I guess I was saying slightly sorted. Something that not sorted but won't take much time to get sorted. maybe like changing every tenth element or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can even create an array with data elements of a particular sequence such as prime numbers, factors or some series like fibonacci series.

Example:

```
class Fibonacci { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int array[] = new int[100]; 
        System.out.println("*****Fibonacci Series*****"); 
        int f1, f2=0, f3=1; 
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) { 
            array[i] = f3;
            f1 = f2; 
            f2 = f3; 
            f3 = f1 + f2; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even make it so how sorted it is can easily be changed by the user. This is a lot more code to write, but works in essence by swaping a certain number of spots in the array. That number can change by the user. I put 0 to 100 before swaping the numbers, but all that matters is it is a well orderd math pattern.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package partlysorted;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Library computer
 */
public class PartlySorted {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


    //scanner for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //intro
    System.out.println("Welcome to the partly sorted pogram");
    System.out.println("This will make a partly sorted list of integers");

    //the numbers
   int[] nums = new int[100];

   //how unsorted for it to be
   int suffels = -1;

   //when to show a typo message 
   boolean firstLoop = true;

   while(suffels  < 0 || suffels > 100)
   {
        if(firstLoop) 
        {
           System.out.println("Please enter how sorted sorted you want (0 to 100, no decimals)");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Looks like you made a typo");
            System.out.println("Please enter a integer from 0 to 100");
        }
        suffels = input.nextInt();
        firstLoop = false;
   }



   //fill it sorted first

   for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
   {
       nums[i] = i;
   }

   //suffle the array
   for(int swaps = 0; swaps < suffels; swaps++)
   {
       int firstPlace = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
       int secondPlace = (int)(Math.random() * 100);

       //swap the places
       int temp = nums[firstPlace];
       nums[firstPlace] = nums[secondPlace];
       nums[secondPlace] = temp;
   } 

   //printing it out
   for(int n: nums)
   {
       System.out.println(n);
   }
  }

}
```